# jQuery get (changing) mouse position as long as mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I need a method witch gives the mouse x and y positions as long as the mouse is down and on any changing mouse position.

For getting the mouse location I use this function:

```
var mouseIsDown = function(e) {
  xPosition = e.clientX;
  yPosition = e.clientY;
  console.log(xPosition + ' ' + yPosition);
}
```

This works and gives me the location each time I press. But I need it continue so I made a interval function:

```
$(function() {
   var timeout;
   $('#canvas').on('mousedown', function(e){
       mouseIsDown(e);
       timeout = setInterval(function(){mouseIsDown(e);}, 100);
   });
   $('#canvas').on('mouseup', function(){
       clearInterval(timeout);
   });
});
```

So this gives me the mouse down position as long as I hold mouse down every 100ms. No I need to add on mouse position changing or an interval like I have but each time new x and y positions instead of every time te same. Still practicing on java jquery and cant figure it out.

Link is online:
http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/test/index.html ->console.log on canavas
ps. noticed online the window sizes is not always correctly (working on that)

Comment: Why don't you use mousemove? http://jsfiddle.net/1wpcogab/

Comment: Wasn't even familiar with mouseover. Thanks a lot!!